# the call to service is not executed

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-httpclient

in ngOnInit, I call a service to get the token, but it doesn't work, it's like that part of the code is omitted, it doesn't appear in the network requests, the service works because I use it in another component later, but I need to use it now from there, that file is the app.component.ts

```
//imports
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  title = 'cor4edu-fe';
  menu: NbMenuItem[];
  alive: boolean = true;

  constructor(private sidebarService: NbSidebarService,
              private appMenu: AppMenu, 
              public auth: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.auth.getTokenSilently$().subscribe((token) => {
      console.log(token);
      localStorage.setItem("Token", token);
    })
    this.myFuncion();
    this.initMenu();
  }

  getToken() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.auth.getTokenSilently$().subscribe(token => resolve(token));
    });
    }
    async myFuncion() {
    const token = await this.getToken();
    console.log(token);
    }
  toggle() {
    this.sidebarService.toggle(true);
    return false;
  }
  initMenu() {
    const token= localStorage.getItem("Token");
    const tokenPayload = decode(token);
    const permissions=tokenPayload['permissions'];

    this.appMenu.getMenu()
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
      .subscribe(menu => {
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("Token"));
        const exist = (menu, permissions) => menu.filter(el1=>permissions.some(el2=> "/"+el2.split(":")[1]==el1.link));
        const menun=exist(menu, permissions);

        if(this.auth.isAuthenticated()){
          this.menu = menun;
        }else{
          this.menu=[
            {
              title: 'Dashboard',
              icon: 'home-outline',
              link: '/',
              home: true,
              children: undefined,
            }
          ]
        }
      });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.alive = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any filers applied to your browser's network tab? Also,  add error and complete callbacks in subscribe and see if there's any error.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure no request is coming up and the service is fine, there's no mistake @AkshayRana

Answer (score 1):

Your component does not implement OnInit interface, so ngOnInit won't be called.